# List contains method in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dart-pub

Contain method can not detect the object inside of list
What is the reason of that?

I expected to get the result of if block
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u33PW.png)[Look at this picture as well.In the second picture it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYHmT.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `==` operator on `Country` like so to get it to work:

```
class Country {
  bool? brotherCountry;
  String? name;
  Country(this.brotherCountry, this.name);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other is Country) {
      return name == other.name && brotherCountry == other.brotherCountry;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => brotherCountry.hashCode ^ name.hashCode;
}
```

Alternatively, there's this package https://pub.dev/packages/equatable, and you can use it like so:

```
class Country extends Equtable {
  bool? brotherCountry;
  String? name;
  Country(this.brotherCountry, this.name);

  @override
  List<Object> props => [brotherCountry, name];
}
```

As pointed about by jamesdlin, it's not because of `call by value`

From [Effective dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-override-hashcode-if-you-override-), it says:

> Any two objects that are equal must have the same hash code. Otherwise, maps and other hash-based collections will fail to recognize that the two objects are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir,but I want to understand it fully.What is happening in the background of this .Could you please explain why we have to tell Dart?

Comment: Call-by-value is a completely unrelated concept.

Answer (score 0):

it's because your `Contact` object has no `==` relation between its instances,
so trying to compare two instances like this:

```
Contact(false, "") == Contact(false, "") // false
```

And the `contains` method follows the same comparison I did to find if a list contains that object.

It would help if you told `Dart` when two objects of that class should be considered equal to each other, by overriding the `==` operator like this:

```
class Country {
  final bool? brotherCountry;
  final String? name;
  Country(this.brotherCountry, this.name);
  
  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Country other) {
    return other.name == name && other.brotherCountry ==brotherCountry;
    
  }
}
```

now trying this:

```
Country(false, "") == Country(false, "") // true
```

and so on now the `contains` method will work as you expect

```
[Country(false, ""), Country(false, "test")].contains(Country(false, "")); // true
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir,but I want to understand it fully.What is happening in the background of this .Could you please explain why we have to tell Dart?